# TTWebController autorotate to landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, autorotate

I can't seem to get my `TTWebController` to autorotate. My `UITabBar` subclass responds to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` on all my views except for my `TTWebController` subclass. That class responds itself but doesn't rotate even though I return YES.

This is what my `TTWebController` subclass looks like:

http://snipt.org/wpnM

This is what I've been testing in my `UITabBar` subclass:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: %@", [[TTNavigator navigator] visibleViewController]);
if ([[[TTNavigator navigator] visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[TTWebController class]]) {
    return YES;
}

// if you're in the "more..." tab and the topViewController is a TTWebController
// Note: this is required because of a Three20 bug where [[TTNavigator navigator] visibleViewController]
// doesn't work properly if you're in the "more..." tab
if ([self.moreNavigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[TTWebController class]]) {
    return YES;
}

// Still here? Return YES only if portrait
return (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

// Stefan

Comment: I'm guessing one issue you're having is the web controller is being added as a subview to UIWindow where it already has an added UIViewController.  This is the same issue I'm having although not sure how best to work around it.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Haven't found one yet. I'm not actively searching for one right now, but I would love to find one! :)